# How to check if '*' exists in an array in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a calculator in **Maven** and I got stuck when I was trying to implement multiplication. When I changed the **args array** in `launch.json` to `2 * 6`, it returned nothing.I also tried - `"\\*` but nothing happened. Also when I put the multiplication boolean to `boolean mul = Arrays.stream(args).anyMatch("".equals);`, It worked.

Here is my code -

```
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 * Hello world!
 */

public final class App {
    

    /**
     * @param args The arguments of the program.
     */


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean plus = Arrays.stream(args).anyMatch("+"::equals);
        boolean minus = Arrays.stream(args).anyMatch("-"::equals);
        boolean div = Arrays.stream(args).anyMatch("/"::equals);
// here -> 
boolean mul = Arrays.stream(args).anyMatch("*"::equals);
/**
Or should I put it like this ->
boolean mul = Arrays.stream(args).anyMatch("\\*"::equals);
*/
        if (plus == true) {
            String plus1 = args[0];
            String plus2 = args[2];
            int plus1_int = Integer.parseInt(plus1);
            int plus2_int = Integer.parseInt(plus2);
            System.out.println(plus1_int + plus2_int);
        }else {
            ;
        }

        if (minus == true) {
             String min1 = args[0];
             String min2 = args[2];
             int min1_int = Integer.parseInt(min1);
             int min2_int = Integer.parseInt(min2);
             System.out.println(min1_int - min2_int);
        }else {
            ;
        }
        

        if (div == true) {
            String div2 = args[2];
            String div1 = args[0];
            int div1_int = Integer.parseInt(div1);
            int div2_int = Integer.parseInt(div2);
            System.out.println(div1_int / div2_int);
          }else {
            ;
        }
 // and here ->
        if (mul == true) {
            String mul1 = args[0];
            String mul2 = args[2];
            int mul1_int = Integer.parseInt(mul1);
            int mul2_int = Integer.parseInt(mul2);
            System.out.println(mul1_int * mul2_int);
        }else { 
            ;
        }

        
        

    }
}
```

Have I done something wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`*` when you use it on command line it refers to file or directory existing in the working directory. Therefore, your args instead of having `2`, `*`, `6` it will be `2`, `file1`, `directory1`, `etc`, `6`.

The solution is to escape it by quote or double quote.

```
2 '*' 6
```

or

```
2 "*" 6
```

Comment: But I already have double quotes around `*`, look at my args list - `"args": ["2",  "*"  ,"6"]`

Comment: Did you mean something else?

Comment: I've tested your code, it works perfectly when i put `2 '*' 6` instead of `2 * 6`. You can display each item or your `args` to see the difference using `System.out.println()` or via debug.

Comment: I've runned the code with command line `java -jar <you file jar> 2 '*' 6`

Comment: Can you please explain what I did wrong because I don't understand

Comment: How do you do to run the code? Because i use directly the jar file generated by `mvn clean install`.

Comment: I don't use a jar file to run this, I just have a launch.json and a java file. I just run the java file in the terminal.

Comment: Sorry for the later responnse (i've done some stuff). What do you mean by `launch.json`? A configuration file on Visual Studio Code? If, yes i just use `"args": "2 * 6"`. There is no problem for my side. My launch.json is configured with version `0.2.0`.

Comment: Yes it is given by vscode, but I pass as an array, like - "args": ["1", "*", "8"].  not in one string.

Comment: For me, array is not authorised. Only string is valid.

Comment: Okay, so let me try with a string instead of an array, I'll tell you if it works